# What are the requirements work permit visa from Ghana?

Tags: working-visas

What are the requirement for a work permit visa for UK from Ghana?

I work with a multinational company and I would like to have the experience working outside Ghana.

Comment: I'd expect your employer to handle this for you.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely asking about a UK Tier 2 (General) visa for which you will need to have a job offer, a certificate of sponsorship from that employer, and be able to pass an assessment system. To evaluate your eligibility, and for step-by-step guidance, your primary resource is the [UK Government's detailed information on work visas](https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-general).

Comment: Assuming the OP's multinational company has a UK branch that they'd be transfering over to work with, wouldn't the [Tier 2 (Intra-company Transfer) visa](https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-intracompany-transfer-worker-visa) be the right one then?

Comment: @Gagravarr might be, although the OP doesn't mention company transfer to the UK. However, the linked info would point them in the right direction, using the info one provides.